# Is programming Arduino a subject of CSE(computer science) at university?

Tags: arduino, programming

If get admitted in "**computer science and Engineering**" department of any university, would there be any subject for programming Arduino? 
This Arduino also looks like a subject of "**Mechanical Engineering**" ... Can anyone explain me, in which department "**Programming hardware**" belongs...

Comment: Microcontrollers fall under Electrical and Computer Engineering. Least the universities I know about in my area (Canada). But why dont you just ask the university ? Or look at their curriculum and course calendar to see whats covered and where ?

Comment: There probably won't be a subject dedicated to Arduino boards, but usually there is a class called "Embedded Systems" of some sort.  These classes study various aspects of micro-controllers which the Arduino is.

Comment: Where I work we teach Embedded Systems as part of Computer Engineering using ARM Cortex-M3 microcontrollers, but microcontrollers are not taught as part of Computer Science. As far as I know, the Arduino is not used as a formal part of any course.

Comment: I teach microcontroller programming. This year I switched from PIC 16F887 to Cortex LPC1114. If I would use the Arduino as hardware plaform, I would not use the Arduino development environment, as it hides a lot of details that I think students should learn.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about engineering education, only specific technical questions about actual practice are on topic here.  It also falls under the prohibition on questions which are opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Computer science" is algorithms and other "big picture" and theoretical items. Practical learning such as embedded development (with MCUs or otherwise) falls under "computer engineering".

Comment: Funny, Computer Science here was another name for Computer Programming.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is "computer science" = "doing things", "computer engineering" = "getting things done".

Comment: @Passerby In the US "computer science" and "computer engineering" are distinct disciplines, mainly because the body that accredits these university programs has different requirements for the degrees.

Comment: In Canada, computing science and computer engineering are also different. Is it mandatory for computing science to learn verilog or VHDL? Where I am it was mandatory for the computer engineers to take at least one course in it. I believe the computer engineers go more into the hardware end while computing science goes more into the abstracted algorithmic end of things.